# Algorithm match class distribution of two datasets

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have MC(Monte Carlo/simulation) and data each having events in two classes 0 and 1. I am trying to write an algorithm such that I can match the number of events in class 0 and 1 of MC to data i.e I want to correct MC events by moving them fro one class to other such that the ratio of events in the two classes for both data and MC is same. The way I proceeded is:

1. Train a GradientBoostingClassifier from scikit ensemble for both data and MC individually(say data_clf and mc_clf)

   ```
    mc_clf.fit(X_mc, Y_mc)
    data_clf.fit(X_data , Y_data)
   ```
2. Now, if X_mc is my input variable, use predict_proba to predict the probability of classifier of data and MC using MC inputs ONLY i.e

   ```
    y_mc = smcclf.predict_proba(X_mc)
    y_data = sdataclf.predict_proba(X_mc)
   ```
3. After this, I try to move the events of MC from one class to another by comparing their probability in data and MC.

   ```
    for i in range(0, len(mc)):
        if (mc.loc[i]['mc_class'] == 0): 
            wgt = y_data[i][0]/ y_mc[i][0]
            if (wgt<1): mc.loc[i]['mc_class_corrected'] = 1
            else: mc.loc[i]['mc_class_corrected'] = mc.loc[i]['mc_class'] 


        if (mc.loc[i]['mc_class'] == 1): 
            wgt = y_data[i][1]/ y_mc[i][1]
            if (wgt<1) : mc.loc[i]['mc_class_corrected'] = 0
            else: mc.loc[i]['mc_class_corrected'] = mc.loc[i]['mc_class']
   ```

In the end what happens is that initially suppose I had more events in class 0 than 1 in MC as compared to data. So I expect events from class 0 to move to class 1. However, I see that almost >95% of my events in class 0 of MC are moving to class 1 while I was expecting only about 30% of events to move (when compared to the number of events in data and MC)?
Is there any mistake in this ideology of working?

Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @desertnaut Its not that didn't try working it out.. Its that it didn't work the way I thought of using probability condition that I mentioned in "Additions"

Comment: an attempt means a *coding* attempt, which must be shown and shared, otherwise the question is off-topic here

Comment: Maybe CrossValidated SE is more suitable for this question?

Comment: What exactly is a MC ?

Comment: @MohammedKashif Monte Carlo events or simulated events. By data, I mean real data events.

Comment: In a case like this including some small sample data set will always get you more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a question not suited to stackoverflow, if you post elsewhere let me know and can move this. But to point out some issues I see:

- Why does the MC simulation not generate the correct weights of classes? It should be able to, given the correct prior distributions from data. 'correcting' the output seems dodge.
- You look to be using the ratio of probabilities from the classifier to determine if the class should change, not the actual class ratio. So it can never be expected to get to the 'correct' class distribution.
- All this is telling you (if most are switching from 0 to 1) is that `y_mc[i][0]` > `y_data[i][0]`. So it is more confident about the MC classifier being a 0, so it switches it to a 1.
- If the classifier for the `y_mc` and the `y_data` is always the MC one, it will obviously be more confident on predicting the MC data, as that is what it is trained on.
- You have no training or testing splits, so the above point about always being more confident is amplified as you will be massively overfitting to the X_mc set.

Very difficult to tell how accurate these points are without sample data (to see what the actual values are for the predictions, etc.) or actual code (the names of your classifiers change, indicates not the actual code).